# Unwanted bar line in Sibelius 7.5

Tags: sibelius

I've been adding lyrics to a composition in Sibelius 7.5, and it's shuffling around a lot of stuff in the piece - most of which I can go and fix easily enough.

In this particular part, it's moved this bar line over and clefs etc. - it looks quite odd/unnecessary. I've tried clicking on it and deleting but it does nothing. Anyone know how I can get rid of it. The two bars either side are both from the same part of the song and there is no need for it there.

[image]

Comment: You should post this question to Sibelius' own user support forum, here. http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3

Answer (score 1):

Found a way around it using the inspector tool, which allows me to hide them.

Comment: The reliable way to permanently get rid of these strange artifacts would be to create an entirely new blank score with the same layout of staves, time signatures and key signatures, and then copy and paste all the notes from the original document into the new document. Generally only the notes and things attached to notes will copy over; the layout of the staves and their key signatures, time signatures, and bar lines will not copy over.

Comment: If you sign up with the Sibelius user forum and make a post about this, you can upload your actual Sibelius document attached to your post. Members of the forum will download your document and examine it for you and suggest how to repair it.

Comment: You should update your copy of Sibelius. Sibelius 7.5.1 is a free update for Sibelius 7.5 owners. It contains a lot of bug fixes. I believe you can still download the updater from the Sibelius website, even though the newest (paid upgrade) version is Sibelius 8.01.

Answer (score 0):

Select the measure after the extra barline and clef.  In the Inspector, set Gap Before Bar to zero.

This happens sometimes with scores imported from another program.  Or it can be caused by you dragging the ends of lines around and then re-formatting so that the old line break is now mid-line.